# Is this a memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

SrchItemEditDetail is a frame
PageSearchFieldEnumMV is a Page
Below is called many times

```
private void Revise_Helper(FieldDef SearchFieldSelected, enumAndOr paramAndOr)
{
   PageSearchFieldEnumMV nextPage = new PageSearchFieldEnumMV(SearchFieldSelected, paramAndOr);
   SrchItemEditDetail.Content = nextPage;
}
```

Other methods fill SrchItemEditDetail.Content with other Pages.

Is this a memory leak?

If so can I fix it with

```
SrchItemEditDetail.Content = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a memory leak?

No, not really. The previous pages will be garbage-collected.

> If so can I fix it with `SrchItemEditDetail.Content = null;`

That is of little use. The previous content will become unreachable anyway.

But there are potential problems. When the Frame somehow keeps other  references to a Content page (for example through an event) then you might have a leak.

And when `PageSearchFieldEnumMV` holds resource you are not freeing them timely. In that case, or in any case to be safe, use:

```
PageSearchFieldEnumMV nextPage = new PageSearchFieldEnumMV(...);

if (SrchItemEditDetail.Content != null)
   SrchItemEditDetail.Content.Dispose();   // may need a typecast here

SrchItemEditDetail.Content = nextPage;
```

Comment: Thanks, how does .NET know the previous pages can be garbage collected?  Need to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: When they become 'unreachable'. Read up on how the GC works in general.

Comment: Error Object does not support Dispose.   I will read up on GC in general.   I have some users reporting rare OOM errors but they are under Citrix and I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Not the comment about typecasting. Pick a parent class of PageSearchFieldEnumMV.

Comment: It derives but Page but this fails ((Page)SrchItemEditDetail.Content).Disose()

Comment: Correct, Page is not `IDisposable`. Surprised me a little.